# Print rows of a data frame as a string

Tags: r

Lets say i have a data frame

```
dd <- data.frame(x = 1:8, f = gl(2,4), ch = I(letters[1:8]))
```

my `first` row has the following elements - `1 1 a`
so for first row i want to print

```
' i dont have 1 out of 1 in a'
```

I want to do this for `each row.` How can this be done?

Comment: Try `with(dd, paste("I don't have", x, "out of", f, "in", ch))`

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect!